# Hovering changes opacity again and again

Tags: html, css

The problem is the following: I have a gallery plugin on Wordpress, called Fancy Plugin installed. Works fine, except now when I look at the gallery, the images are very very faint (the opacity is very low), then, if I hover over the image, it gets less opaque, then I hover again and it gets better and better. I need like 10-15 mouse passes for the image to be on opacity close to 0.9, but then it does not change anymore. I want to switch this off completely, I do not want any kind of opacity in the gallery, I want it to be 1. I don't know what CSS to use to do this.

I tried inspecting with Chrome DevTools, that's how I found this piece of code:

```
<img class="fg-thumb" src="http://www.faktumkft.hu/wp-content/plugins/radykal-fancy-gallery/admin/timthumb.php?src=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.faktumkft.hu%2Fwp-content%2Ffancygallery%2F2%2F2%2Fvizszintes_palcas_korlat__09.jpg&amp;w=200&amp;h=150&amp;zc=0&amp;q=100" alt="Vízszintes pálcás korlát, ívelt" style="width: 200px; height: 150px; opacity: 0.825593;">
```

I can see the weird opacity number that seems to be kind of random, there, but I don't know how to change it. Can someone help please? Thanks!

Comment: opacity is loading from javascript, you need to edit the plugin(which is a bad idea), or you need to override opacity with !important

Comment: don't use opacity simply put like this <img src="sampl.png" alt="photo"> thats it its going to work dear @Andras

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fast fix would be adding next to your css:

```
.fg-thumb{
    opacity:1 !important;
}
```

However what you find pointing to so called in-line styles, and they may come from some javascript (may be from that plugin). You may want to read some documentation or/and check source code if it is available.

Comment: Thanks, the quick fix worked! I didn't write the !important line at first, and it did not work without that.